# What is kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, get, nsurlerrordomain

In the last question I posted, I have been getting a NSURLErrorDomain when I append a JSON string into my URL using the GET method. Now, someone pointed out that I should percent encode the whole JSON string so that it will be URL compatible. When I did that however, I received another kind of error: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork code 303. I researched about this and unfortunately I couldn't find a suitable explanation for this error. The closest thing I understand about this error is that it seems like I'm sending huge memory to the server.

Can anyone give me a nice and simple explanation about this?

Comment: how about you change the GET method to POST method ?

Comment: Hi @arufian. Ever since I posted this question, we decided to change the method from GET to POST. Now everything is working without errors. Still, I want to know why posting JSON through GET method gives me this error. So if you know why, kindly answer the question so I can accept it properly. Thanks. :)

Comment: maybe your/that's application API that you want to access is using different method (I mean they use POST instead of GET) ... In my experience I just mistook the API http request method :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the details of your specific error but according to the Apple Documentation

```
kCFErrorHTTPParseFailure      = 303
```

So it looks like the encoding wasn't understood by the server - maybe there was some part of the JSON string to blame. Without taking a look at the JSON string I am just guessing :-)

[Wiki on percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)